# Bitnami npm install canvas

Tags: canvas, npm, cairo, bitnami, pango

after trying every solution on Internet i am stuck with this error

```
node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/bitnami/SmartDoorbell/node_modules/canvas/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
  COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
In file included from /usr/include/cairo/cairo-ft.h:50:0,
                 from ../src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.h:17,
                 from ../src/Canvas.cc:9:
/opt/bitnami/common/include/fontconfig/fontconfig.h:116:30: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
 #define FC_CACHE_SUFFIX      ".cache-"FC_CACHE_VERSION
                              ^
/opt/bitnami/common/include/fontconfig/fontconfig.h:117:31: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
 #define FC_DIR_CACHE_FILE     "fonts.cache-"FC_CACHE_VERSION
                               ^
/opt/bitnami/common/include/fontconfig/fontconfig.h:118:32: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
 #define FC_USER_CACHE_FILE     ".fonts.cache-"FC_CACHE_VERSION
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-types.h:195:0,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-font.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-attributes.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pangocairo.h:25,
                 from ../src/Canvas.h:17,
                 from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
/usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-bidi-type.h:129:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 G_DEPRECATED_FOR(g_unichar_get_mirror_char)
                 ^
In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:17:0,
                 from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
/usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pangocairo.h:92:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 G_DEPRECATED_FOR(pango_font_map_create_context)
                 ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/bitnami/SmartDoorbell/node_modules/canvas/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
gyp ERR! command "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin" "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/bitnami/SmartDoorbell/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin" "/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs canvas
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/bitnami/SmartDoorbell/npm-debug.log
```

installed cairo with apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg8-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++ 
apt-get install libpixman-1-dev libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev  libjpeg-dev

Added path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH to remove "cairo not found" error.
Now all i have is this. On local computer the above apt command was enough to install canvas so it must have something to do with bitnami's server.